# C# How to insert/update the parent and child data to the sql database using entity framework in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm developing a website using asp.net mvc 5 and the database that I'm using is MS SQL Server Management Studio 17. Right now I want to insert and update some data with parent and child relationship to the database using entity framework in one shot.

The parent table(Accounts):

```
public class Accounts
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    //The foreign key in database
    public int UserAddressId { get; set; }

    //The child collection
    public virtual ICollection<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

The child table(Address):

```
public class Addresses
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddressId")]
    public virtual Accounts Account { get; set; }
}
```

I know in sql if I want to insert data into the parent table, I have to create the data for the child table first, and then insert data the data to the parent table. However, I don't know how to do it in entity framework.

Question 1: 
Am I setting up the relationship in the entity classes correctly?

Question 2: 
How do I insert/update the data to the database using entity framework? I want to do it in one shot, please provide me some code examples.

Comment: *I want to do it in one shot* That depends on what you want to insert. Please show your present code.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, I want to insert the address and account to the database. Since the UserAddressId in Account table is a foreign key pointing to the AddressId of the Address table, I have to insert the address data first before inserting the data to the Account table. Also, I need the AddressId in the Address table for the Account table as the foreign key after the Address data is created.

Answer (score 0):

Models:

```
public class Account
{
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
public class Address
{
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}
```

---

DbContext:

```
public partial class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public AppContext(): base("name=ApplicationDbContext")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

    }

    public virtual DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

---

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    ...        
}
```

Then take a look [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx) for add and update operations.